# Answer : Amount to (Why)

Tags: grammar

I came across with a question and i did not understand the answer. Someone can help me?

Question : It's quite obvious that whatever you like to call his remarks they are impolite and amount to slander.
Answer: (b) amount

Comment: Please explain more about how this question works. Then your question can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking why  "amount to" is correct in that context. It means "correspond to":

***[Amount to something](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/amount-to-sth)***:

> to be the same as something, or to have the same effect as something:
>
> - *His behaviour amounted to serious professional misconduct.
>     He gave what amounted to an apology on behalf of his company.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)